# hibernate mysql connection failed

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I was working on simple project using Hibernate. I put all the jar file including mysql-connectors to WEB-INF libs folder. Still it threw error. Please help me with these.

```
Exception
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:131)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:304)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1363)
    first.doPost(first.java:37)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)


Root Cause
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample
    java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:192)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:278)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:297)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:169)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1363)
    first.doPost(first.java:37)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

this is my code:

NewFile.jsp

Insert title here

ID:

Name:

user.java

public class user {

```
private int uid;

private String user;

public int getUid() {

    return uid;

}

public void setUid(int uid) {

    this.uid = uid;

}

public String getUser() {

    return user;

}

public void setUser(String user) {

    this.user = user;

}
```

}

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"

    "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

```
<session-factory>

    <property
```

name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

```
    <property
```

name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>


    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property
```

name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

```
    <mapping resource="user.hbm.xml" />

</session-factory>
```

user.hbm.xml

"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"

"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

```
  <id name = "uid" type = "int" column = "id">

     <generator class="native"/>

 </id>

  <property name = "user" column = "name" type = "string"/>
```

``

Comment: maybe you are missing `mysql-connector` jar in your buildpath

Comment: which buildpath ?